# Get map data from another map - Ionic 4, Firestore

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a map data from inside another map in Firestore, is there any way to do so?

[image]

I want to be able to pull the `price` & `descr` data at once without having to call them one by one. I managed to pull only one of the data by specifying it's exact directory just like in the code:

[From my .ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNDBG.png)

[html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vgFp.png)

it would be great if someone can help me solve this, i am very new at all this :")
thanks!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you should copy the relevant code into your question and format it so that it's easy to read, instead of providing links to screenshots.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the tip! will do that on the next one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible to filter nested maps in firestore. either you get all data and filter them client side or remodel your data collections schemas in firestore. you can for example convert the plans to an array of maps:

```
plan [
   {desc: "things", price: 24}
]
```

and then use "array-contains" query in firestore:

```
db.collection("cafes")
  .where("plans", "array-contains", {desc: "things", price: 12})
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data());
    });
  });
```

however, you will need to pass the whole object as an argument for array-contains to work.

Comment: thank you!! I've changed it to an array of maps and i got what i needed

Comment: Can you also help me figure out how i can capture data into a map and push that map into an array in firestore? thanks.

Comment: It would be better to ask this on a separate question as one thread should correspond to one issue.